# Descending count with iteration - Python

Tags: python, loops, count

I need help on how to iterate over rows. For example, let's say I have a variable

```
a = 30
```

What I would like to do is using a loop in order to obtain something like that:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,.....,0     (30 zeros, because a=30)
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,....,1      (29 ones)
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,...,2       (28 twos)
.....
30                          (1 thirty)
```

I tried something like this:

```
L = [0]
for x in L:
   while L[x] < a:
     print(x)
     L[0] = L[0]+1
```

But doing this I obtain only 30 zeros. I'm not able to increase L to restart the count.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `for x in L:`, what do you think this means? What is the intended purpose of that loop? How many times do you expect it to run, and what do you expect to be the value of `x` each time? What is `a` in this code? Overall, please try to explain the intended logic, step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using nested loops and reassigning into a temporary list, use the following short approach based on *inversed* `range` and string *multiplication*:

```
a = 30
for fill_v, k in enumerate(range(a + 1, 0, -1)):
    print((f'{str(fill_v)},' * k).rstrip(','))
```

---

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3
4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5
6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6
7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7
8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8
9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10
11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11
12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12
13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14
15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15
16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16
17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17
18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18
19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19
20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20
21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21
22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22
23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23
24,24,24,24,24,24,24
25,25,25,25,25,25
26,26,26,26,26
27,27,27,27
28,28,28
29,29
30
```

Answer (score 0):

the suggestion below needs numpy

```
import numpy as np
a=30
token=0
for i in range(a,0,-1):
    x=np.repeat(token,i)
    print(x)
    token=token+1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start with 30 `0`s, you should end with 0 `30`s [i.e., at 1 `29`],

```py
# for i in range(a): print(','.join([f'{i}']*(a-i))) # OR
for i in range(a): print(*[i]*(a-i), sep=',')
```

You can end at 1 `30` if you start with 31 `0`s [ [output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6ODt.png) ]

```py
for i in range(a+1): print(*[i]*(a-i+1), sep=',')
```

---

If you to save it as an object

```py
{f"{(a-i)} {i}'s": tuple([i]*(a-i)) for i in range(a)}
```

would return a dictionary of tuples

```py
{
   "30 0's":  (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
   "29 1's":  (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
   "28 2's":  (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
   "27 3's":  (3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
   "26 4's":  (4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
   "25 5's":  (5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5),
   "24 6's":  (6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6),
   "23 7's":  (7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7),
   "22 8's":  (8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8),
   "21 9's":  (9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9),
   "20 10's":  (10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10),
   "19 11's":  (11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11),
   "18 12's":  (12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12),
   "17 13's":  (13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13),
   "16 14's":  (14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14),
   "15 15's":  (15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15),
   "14 16's":  (16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16),
   "13 17's":  (17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17),
   "12 18's":  (18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18),
   "11 19's":  (19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19),
   "10 20's":  (20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20),
   "9 21's":  (21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21),
   "8 22's":  (22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22),
   "7 23's":  (23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23),
   "6 24's":  (24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24),
   "5 25's":  (25, 25, 25, 25, 25),
   "4 26's":  (26, 26, 26, 26),
   "3 27's":  (27, 27, 27),
   "2 28's":  (28, 28),
   "1 29's":  (29)
}
```

Comment: how can I store the list of numbers (30 0s, 29 1s ecc..) in a simple list?

Comment: Just **`[[i]*(a-i) for i in range(a)]`** or *`list({...}.values())`*

Answer (score 0):

```
var = 30
count = 0
for i in range(var+1, 0, -1):
    for j in range(0,i):
        print(count, end='', sep='')
    print("\n")
    count = count + 1
```

The code defines two variables var with a value of 30, and count with a value of 0. It then uses a nested for loop to iterate over a range of numbers, starting from var+1 and ending at 0 in descending order. On each iteration of the inner loop, the code prints the current value of the count variable, followed by a newline character. The value of count is incremented by 1 on each iteration of the outer loop. The output is a series of rows, each row containing a different number of the same value, starting from 0 and ending with 30. The number of times each number is printed in each row will be decremented by 1 starting from 30 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

That can be achieved with a simple nested loop as follows:

```
a = 30
for i in range(a+1):
    for j in range(1,a-i+2):
        if j == a-i+1:
            print(i,end='')
        else:
            print(i,end=',')
    print()
```

Notice the if condition to not put ',' at the end as on your example.

The output:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3
4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5
6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6
7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7
8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8
9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10
11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11
12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12
13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13
14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14
15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15
16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16
17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17
18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18
19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19
20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20
21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21
22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22
23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23
24,24,24,24,24,24,24
25,25,25,25,25,25
26,26,26,26,26
27,27,27,27
28,28,28
29,29
30
```